# React Native - how do I trigger a function based off a change in a reducer value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-lifecycle-hooks

I have a question about how to trigger a function in one component on the change of a reducer value from a different component.

I currently have a function in my `Home` component that runs in `ComponentDidMount`. If my value `this.props.reducer.run` is true the function fires. The initial state is set to `true` so the function fires when the app first loads.

In my `Profile` component I have a toggle switch with toggles `this.props.reducer.run` to `true` or `false`. Is it possible to trigger my function in `Home` when a change to the reducer value occurs?

Below is a mock up of the code i have, i am wondering if `ComponentDidUpdate` is what I should be looking at, if so some guidance would be appreciated:

**Home.js**

```
...

myFunction() = > {
   console.log('fired')
}

ComponentDidMount() {
   //runs on load
   if(this.props.reducer.run == true) {
     this.myFunction()
   }
}

...


**Profile.js**

...

toggleRun = () => {
   this.props.setRun(!this.props.reducer.run)
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do this with `componentDidUpdate`. When `componentDidUpdate` is invoked, it will be passed the previous value of your component props (let's call this `prevProps`). By comparing the `prevProps.reducer.run` to `this.props.reducer.run`, you can determine if the value changed and, if it did, call your function accordingly.

Alternatively, if this were a functional component you could achieve the same with `useEffect`.